# How to use the definition of injective, subjective and bijective to show $g=h$

Tags: ring-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are sets.

$f:X\to Y$
$g: Y\to X$
$h: Y\to X $

$g \circ f = 1_X$
$f \circ h = 1_Y$

HINT: Observe that $g = g \circ 1_Y$

**Show that $g=h$**

What I think... is that it is injective (one-to-one) and surjective (onto) so that means the whole thing is bijective

injective means $g(f(x))=1X$ means that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ therefore $x_1=x_2$

surjective means that $f(h(x))=1Y$

$g = g \circ 1Y$  means $g(f(h(x)))$

I don't know how to utilize this information to show $g=h$.

Comment: $g=g\circ (1_Y)=g\circ (f\circ h)=(g\circ f)\circ h=\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can immediately show that it is bijective as follows by using the given hint

$$
g = g\circ 1_Y = g \circ (f\circ h) = (g\circ f) \circ h = 1_X \circ h = h
$$

I think this question got answered somewhere, but I'm too lazy to search for that because it's faster to just write the solution immediately :)